# How to display azure resources in tabular form python SDK

Tags: python, json, azure, format

**I created a `ResourceManagementClient` using the azure python sdk:**

- `resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(service_credential, subscription_id)`

**The output produced via...**

```
for item in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
    print(item)
```

**...is difficult to read and its not in valid json format.**

```
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/azureMaps', 'name': 'azureMaps', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499748>, 'location': 'westus', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/speechToText', 'name': 'speechToText', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba4997f0>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/neo4j-rg', 'name': 'neo4j-rg', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499b00>, 'location': 'westus', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/things', 'name': 'things', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499a90>, 'location': 'westus', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/appInsights', 'name': 'appInsights', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499a20>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/computerVision', 'name': 'computerVision', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499c50>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/dataBricks', 'name': 'dataBricks', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499be0>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/databricks-rg-databricksDEV-v6oygdyuh3sii', 'name': 'databricks-rg-databricksDEV-v6oygdyuh3sii', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499d30>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/dataBricks/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/databricksDEV', 'tags': {}}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/cool', 'name': 'cool', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499cf8>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/wsFunctionApp', 'name': 'wsFunctionApp', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499e48>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/azureStorage', 'name': 'azureStorage', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499dd8>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/azureSQL', 'name': 'azureSQL', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499d68>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/azureFunction', 'name': 'azureFunction', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499f28>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/mySub/resourceGroups/NetworkWatcherRG', 'name': 'NetworkWatcherRG', 'properties': <azure.mgmt.resource.resources.v2018_05_01.models.resource_group_properties_py3.ResourceGroupProperties object at 0x7f0fba499f98>, 'location': 'westus2', 'managed_by': None, 'tags': None}
```

**Can someone help me pretty print this output into something like a `display()` table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want this, you can print all the properties you want of the `item` directly.

Something like:

```
print(item.id)
print(item.location)
print(item.tags)
```

[image]

Or if you want a valid json, you could custom the properties you want like below, the output is a valid json:

```
import json

result = []
for item in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
    additional_properties = item.additional_properties
    id = item.id
    location = item.location
    tags = item.tags
    type = item.type
    row = {"additional_properties": additional_properties, "id": id, "location": location, "tags": tags, "type": type}
    result.append(row)
data = json.dumps(result)
print(data)
```

If you want to make the output easy to read, you could use the [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) Tool.

[image]